# Jquery Keyboard Event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to simulate a Keyboard event with jquery. What I want is when I click a button, I want a character to appear in a textarea. I need the action to be a keyboard simulation not a simple append. I have tried all the possible solutions on the web without any success, so I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

Here is my HTML/JS/Jquery code :

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
        <input type='text' id="input"></input>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function simulateKeyPress() {
                document.getElementById("text").focus();
                var e = $.Event("keypress");
                e.which = 97;
                $("input").trigger(e);
            }
        </script>
        <br/>
        <button id="button" onclick='simulateKeyPress()'>Press Me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, when the button is clicked, I only get a focus on the text element, but no character appears, any ideas?

looks like I was not clear enough. Here is another sample, I am using the [MouseTrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) library to capture keyboard events. 
Here is my code.

```
<html>
<header>
<title>test</title>
</header>
<script type='text/javascript' src='MouseTrap.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>

<body>
<input type='text' class="mousetrap" id="input"></input>
<script type='text/javascript'>
Mousetrap.bind('4',  function(){alert("you pressed 4" );});
function simulateKeyPress(character) {
        document.getElementById("input").focus();
        var input = $('#input');
        input.val(input.val() + character);
}
</script>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick='simulateKeyPress(4)'>Press Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code, whenever you press '4' on the keyboard, an alert box will appear. All I want is when I click the button, the same event to be created. Ideas?

Comment: I think you should have a set of values such as characters put into an array and when you hit that particular button containing the specific index, it will output the character onto the textarea.

Comment: I am only testing with one value for now, when this piece of code works, I will proceed to add the rest of the values

Comment: Why do you want or need the keypress event for?

Comment: I want the character to appear in the box via keyboard event trigger, isn't it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution to simulate the keypress :

```
var input = $('#input');

$('#button').click(function(){
    // Add a character to the input
    input.val(input.val() + 'x');
    // Trigger the keypress event
    input.keypress();
});

// Check if it work
input.on('keypress', function(){
    alert('key pressed!');
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HighKickX/JHjRe/1/).

Comment: Your code works perfectly, but I do not want to use an append, simply because I want to insert this code in my project which relies on canvas element that does not have an append function.

Comment: Could you complete your question and add sample code of that canvas?

Comment: I did add a sample code, I cannot add the canvas sample, because it is too large ~4MB, the sample that I added should do

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not perform default actions when you fire it from javascript. So the only way is to create your own vent handler :

```
function simulateKeyPress() {
    document.getElementById("text").focus();
    var e = $.Event("keypress");
    e.which = 97;
    $("input").trigger(e);
}

$("input").on('keypress', function(e){
    //append e.which to your input here
});
```

Comment: My problem is only with the append function, my project relies on canvas element that does not have this function, that is why I am trying to simulate a keyboard event that will be captured by my canvas.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to post another question with your actual issue with canvas?

Comment: I added the a sample code, the canvas sample could not be added, it is too large ~4MB

Comment: Your updated code didnt clarified your actual problem though. The answer is the same: you cannot fire default event action.
You said that your problem is that you cannot append some data to your canvas. There must be another workaround for this if you explain what do you want to do with your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible to acheieve this without appending the characters manually to the textarea.

The answers that @HighKickX and @claustrofob wrote only triggers the event handler as if the specificed key was pressed, but not actually presses that key like happens when a key is pressed on the keyboard (probably due to security reasons).

Because only the event is fired but the key is not actually pressed the textarea won't have that character added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input id="field">

<button id="x" class="button">submit</button>

$(".button").click(function() {

   var value = $("#field").val();

   $("#field").val( $("#field").val() + value);

});
```